# Parsing HTML with HTML Agility pack. Multiple Nodes and in a text box. Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I have the following code below. I am able to get two of the following HTML in one list box.

```cs
 <div class="services">
     <a class="service selected" onclick="serviceNameClick('');" href="#">all</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('1');" href="#">1</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('1A');" href="#">1A</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('71');" href="#">71</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('73');" href="#">73</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('N1');" href="#">N1</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('21A');" href="#">21A</a>  
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('21E');" href="#">21E</a> 
     <a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('21');" href="#">21</a> 
 </div>
```

<sup>[source](http://m.buses.co.uk/stop.aspx?stopid=6884)</sup>

I would like the stops, " all, 1, 2, 12 " etc to be in one line. Each number is to be clickable.

Whats the best way to do this using the current code? If not are there any suggestions on how to improve this?

```cs
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string htmlPage = "";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://m.buses.co.uk/stop.aspx?stopid=6884");
    }

    HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

    List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
    foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'services')]"))
    {
        Movie newMovie = new Movie();
        newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='service selected']").InnerText.Trim();
        newMovie.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='service']").InnerText.Trim();
       // newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='outline']").InnerText.Trim();
        movies.Add(newMovie);
    }
    lstMovies.ItemsSource = movies;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
 {
            Movie newMovie = new Movie();
            newMovie.Summary = div.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='service']").ToString();
          //  newMovie.Title = div.ChildNodes(".//a[@class='service']").ToString();
         //   newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='service']").Attributes.ToString(); 

            var lines = div.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='service']");

            //var lines = div.SelectNodes("./a[contains(@class, 'service')]");
            movies.Add(newMovie);
            //listLines.ItemSource = lines.Select(line => new { Line = line.InnerText });
            lstMovies.ItemsSource = lines.Select(line => new { Line = line.InnerText });
        }



        //listLines.ItemSource = movies.Select(line => new { Line = line.InnerText });
       lstMovies.ItemsSource = movies;


          <ListBox x:Name="lstMovies" Height="335" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Cover}" />
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding target}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Movies}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Summary}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
var lines = div.SelectNodes("./a[contains(@class, 'service')]")
listLines.ItemSource = lines.Select(line => new { Line = line.InnerText }
```

Not sure how you'd want to make them clickable, since I you don't really explain what should happen when you click them.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I need to be able to take the value of the selected item then I will be using that in a different feed. So if a user clicks on 12, I will be able to filter all number 12 bus at a particular stop. Just like how the link works, in my question. Will give this a go.

Comment: Tired this, with some alterations, but it does not return a result.

Comment: Please update the question to show what you did. In the debugger, is the ItemSource properly poulated?